# Handling pyenv command using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pyenv

Im working on logic to automate process of pyenv virtualenv creation using subprocess. Trying to run multiple pyenv shell commands at one go as below

```py
def subprocess_cmd(command):
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    process.poll()
    print (proc_stdout)

def run_cmd():
    
    python_version = "3.9.6"
    dirName = "D:/python_venv" + '/' + str(python_version)
    os.makedirs(dirName, exist_ok=True)

    try:
       subprocess_cmd('pyenv install -l,pyenv install 3.9.0,pyenv local 3.9.6,python -m venv .venv')   
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exception:
        return None

run_cmd()
```

Unfortunately, its not successful. Throwing below error

```
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
pyenv-install: definition not found: -l;

See all available versions with `pyenv install --list'.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: maybe replace `pyenv install -l` with `pyenv install --list`

Comment: Its throwing same issue. Main issue unable to execute multiple commands.

Comment: I can't repro. How are you running the Python instance from which you are attempting to run the subprocess?

Comment: Basically trying to create a directory, in which subprocess runs the pyenv command, which has capability to install python and create python venv. Edited my question and updated with code